# Haskell Servant: 400 Bad Request when using array of custom data type in ReqBody

Tags: haskell, servant

So, I have a simple Id type:

```
newtype Id = Id String
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Generic)

instance ToJSON Id
instance FromJSON Id
instance FromHttpApiData Id where parseUrlPiece = Right . Id . Text.unpack
```

And a servant route defined as so:

```
type SetEntryOrder = "entries" :> "order" :> ReqBody '[JSON] [Id] :> Post '[JSON] [Id]
```

I make a request to it with headers and request body as below:

```
POST /entries/order HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9090
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 199
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://localhost:9090
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:9090/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en

["0pAWSlIHH38sApt0n101X2brrCkyYp","1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","2aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","7T84N81O7T84N81O7T84N81Obeu4JU","vMfOGs2LvMfOGs2LvMfOGs2LzjlQIP","j1Ew8Ju7HzAIv2yH9ohcdl9Wm2o7qx"]
```

But I get back a 400 with the following body (the route is not entered at all):

```
Error in $: expected record (:*:), encountered Array
```

I cloned the github servant repo and grepped for various parts of this but found nothing.

It's perhaps worth noting that I have a bunch of other routes that work fine.

I thought perhaps my `Id` type was not being decoded properly (Aeson expected records or something) but I can use the same thing servant does under the hood without issue in GHCI:

```
> import Servant.API.ContentTypes (eitherDecodeLenient)
> eitherDecodeLenient "[\"hello\",\"hi\"]" :: Either String [Id]
Right [Id "hello",Id "hi"]
```

And defining custom JSON handlers for my Id type like so doesn't help either:

```
instance ToJSON Id where
    toJSON (Id s) = String $ Text.pack s
instance FromJSON Id where
    parseJSON (String s) = return $ Id $ Text.unpack s
    parseJSON _ = empty
```

Sooo, does anyone have an idea why Servant is getting stuck trying to decode my array of Ids and throwing me a 400 rather than getting into my route? :)

**versions**

stack LTS 6.15, which means:

GHC 7.10.3, servant 0.7.1, servant-server 0.7.1, aeson 0.11.2.1

(I tested servant-0.8.1 also but no change)

**Original Code**

https://github.com/jsdw/talklicker/tree/master/server (see Routes.hs for the route definition and Types.hs for the definition of Id)

## Update!

So, the issue appears to be that servant is matching the wrong route, as by passing in the right data to my `/entries/orders` route (in fact, it seems I can replace "orders" with any string, and trailing slash makes no difference!), I can actually get to my `/entries` route. Adding another route piece (eg `:> "dadada"`) to SetEntryOrder and using that allows me to target the correct route.

The routes in question that overlap are:

```
type SetEntryOrder = HasSession :> "order" :> ReqBody '[JSON] [Id] :> Post '[JSON] [Id]
```

and

```
type AddEntry = HasSession :> ReqBody '[JSON] AddEntryInput :> Post '[JSON] Entry
```

noting that both of these are prefixed with "entries" at the top of my Routes.hs file. I have yet to work out why this is the case, but it's a start!

## Update 2!

Problem solved! It in fact was because I had overlapping routes, so my fault! I made things hard for myself because the overlapping route accepted almost any input (but I forgot this!). Swapping the routes around fixed it.

Comment: I’m not sure if this would fix your problem, but you might try dropping the explicit `ToJSON` / `FromJSON` instances and the `Generic` derivation and instead just derive `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` using `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`. That would *ensure* the instance isn’t trying to do anything more complicated than the instance for `String`.

Comment: Good idea, I'll give that a go when I get the chance! I did quite thoroughly test encode/decode however (as well as the eitherDecodeLenient variant) as well as write a custom decoder, and I didn't get anywhere :(

Comment: I'd still worry @AlexisKing might be right. `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` and `DeriveAnyClass` would lead to different results, and depending on how your `.ghci` config file and `cabal` file are setup, the GHCi session may be using something different.

Comment: What are the `servant` and `aeson` versions you're using? Do you have any other route that could possible conflict with the one you think gets processed?

Comment: Good point, I added versions and a link to the full source into the question! I don't believe any other routes can possibly conflict (it's the only one with "order" in at all). @user2141650 I wrote a custom decoder along the lines of `parseJSON (String s) = return $ Id $ Text.unpack s` to avoid that sort of thing and it didn't help matters :(

Comment: @user2141650 fyi I double checked after writing custom parsers again with no luck (added to the original post)

Comment: @fizruk so I think you're onto something (but I'm not sure how it's possible!) - I have been experimenting with throwing different request bodies at the troublesome route, and I managed to get back a very specific error message from another route (specifically, the one declared right next to it, AddEntry)! This is very strange - if you look at my Routes.hs you'll see that it all looks sane (though I am still expecting to find some sort of silly mistake).. I wonder whether there is an off-by-one error in servant somewhere.